# Delphi XE2. How to compile .exe?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have my Delphi program coded and ready to rock and roll, but I can't find the option to compile the .exe.

I'm sure it's obvious, any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to the Delphi IDE Menu  Project -> Compile Project or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd>

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE2. Do you have a link to the IDE you're speaking of?

Comment: Check the online help for RadStudio http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiling,_Building,_and_Running_Applications

Comment: So I see the option, but it's grayed out.

Comment: That is because you are not inside of a project, maybe you are creating  a form or a unit directly, try  File-> New VCL Forms Application and then you will able to compile a new vcl project.

Comment: After I compile it, I dont get an exe, only some odd files and a Win32 folder with a debug folder inside.

Comment: check inside of the debug folder

Comment: @pythondjango, the compiled binary file should be located inside Win32\Debug folder. The type of the produced binary file depends on what you are compiling; if you are compiling a VCL Application, or Console Application, or FireMonkey HD Application, or FireMonkey 3D Application, then you should have an EXE file in Debug folder after compiling the project.

Comment: You are a life saver!!! Thanks. Got her working. Thanks thanks thanks. Oh yea, thanks!

Comment: "I'm using Delphi XE 2 but I don't know how to compile..." this should be voted up ? The question in itself looks like a spam or a joke.